# Is upgrading a pi as simple as swapping the memory cards?

Tags: pi-models

I'm currently using a first generation Pi Model B and have ordered a new Pi 3 Model B+. When it arrives, is it as simple as taking the memory card from the older machine and adding it to the new one?

If not, what else will I need to do to continue with the setup as it is?

(apologies if this is already asked, I've searched and can't find an anwer)

Comment: Which operating system is currently on your sd card ? Was Noobs used to install it ?

Comment: it has rasbian and I installed it with Noobs

Answer (score 2):

Provided the Pi is running Raspbian Stretch, and you upgrade, the SD will work in all models. The model B (pre B+) used full sized SD Cards; all later models use micro SD Cards.

If you are running an older OS it will not work. Your best bet in this case is a new installation. (SD Cards are cheap enough - use a new card; preferably 16GB, as the newer OS are larger - they will run on a 8GB card, but with little space for new files.)

Comment: If Stretch was installed with Noobs, I think Noobs needs updating too.

Answer (score 1):

As Milliways has pointed out, being able to boot your new Pi from the microSD card in your old Pi will depend upon what version of Raspbian is on that card. I recently upgraded an older model Pi from the wheezy distribution, and it took much more time and effort than creating a new SD card. It's fairly straightforward: download a [current image file](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/), "burn" it to a fresh microSD card using [Etcher](https://etcher.io/) or [rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/), make any necessary changes to /boot/config.txt you need, insert the card, apply power and boot.

And the advantage of this approach is that you still have your old Pi to use.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the advice everyone, I ended up formatting a new card and installing each service as I needed it, and then copying the config over from the old Pi. 
About a week later, everything is running fine on the new Pi and I'm trying to think of something to do with the old one.